# How to create a vertical (smooth) Histogram on the y-axis of a function graph for an uncertain x?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, distributions, histograms

This is my first time posting a question in StackExchange. I have encountered a certain problem and I can't seem too find a solution.
Just a word of caution, I am kind of an amateur when it comes to Mathematica and the Wolfram language.

What I would like to do is create a graph of a function `y=f[x]`, to illustrate the difference between optimal ("pointy" edge) and robust ("blunt" edge) solutions.

In the same graph/plot, I would like to show the distribution of the X quantity, correctly placed on the x-axis (under the pointy and blunt edges), as well as the corresponding distributions (preferably Smooth Histograms) of each Y quantity, also correctly placed, but vertically on the y-axis this time.

I have accomplished the first part, but I can't seem to find a way to place the y distributions too.

One way I have thought of facing this problem is to create the two Y-distributions and place them as transposed images on the `plots` plot.
However, my programming abilities limit my end result.

This (low quality) picture I created in Photoshop, illustrates what I would like to do.

[image: Optimal vs Robust Design]

Please help!!

Below is the code I am using.

PS: any other comment, hint or piece of advise is greatly appreciated.

PPS: I also can't get the monochromatic theme to work for the `plots` plot

```
f[x_]=InterpolatingPolynomial[{ { 3.61 ,7.29}, { 5.27, 2.21}, { 6.00, 4.00}, { 6.48, 6.68}, { 8.20, 7.30}, { 9.37, 6.31}, {10.25, 4.92}, {11.26, 3.52}, {12.40, 3.48}, {13.44, 3.48}, {14.28, 3.76}, {15.39, 6.58}, {15.90, 8.62} },x]
FindMinimum[f[x],{x,5}]
```

Result of FindMinimum: `{1.69509,{x->5.45853}}`, the value of which I use in `mopt`, for the pointy edge. For the blunt edge, `mrob=12.5` seemed like a good guess.

```
mopt = 5.45853;
sopt = 0.5;
mrob = 12.5;
srob = sopt;
grob[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[mrob,srob],x];
gopt[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[mopt,sopt],x];

plots=Show[ Plot[ f[x],
                  {x,0,20},
                  RegionFunction->Function[{x,y},3.95<x<15.5],
                  PlotLegends->{"F(x)"},
                  PlotStyle->{Thick, Blue}
                 ],
            Plot[ grob[x],
                  {x,0,20},
                  RegionFunction->Function[{x,y},-srob<(x-mrob)/3<srob],
                  Filling->Axis,
                  PlotLegends->{"Nrob"},
                  PlotStyle->{Red, Dashing[Tiny]}
                 ],
            Plot[ gopt[x],
                  {x,0,20},
                  RegionFunction->Function[{x,y}, -sopt<(x-mopt)/3<sopt],
                  Filling->Axis,
                  PlotLegends->{"Nopt"},
                  PlotStyle->{Green,Dashed}],
                  AxesLabel->{"x","F"},
                  Ticks->None,
                  Axes->{True,True},
                  PlotRange->{{0,17},{0,14}}
                 ]
```

All in order to export it as an .eps image file.

```
Export["robustdesignFinal.eps",plots]
```

The two graphs I would like to add are essentially the ones below:

```
datarob=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mrob, srob],10000]
dataopt=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mopt, sopt],10000]
Adatarob=f[datarob]
Adataopt=f[dataopt]
h1=SmoothHistogram[ Adatarob,
                    Automatic,
                    "PDF",
                    RegionFunction->Function[{x,y},3.3<x<3.6],
                    PlotRange->{{3.3,3.6},{0,15}},
                    Filling->Axis,
                    PlotLegends->{"P(Frob)"},
                    PlotStyle->{Red, Dashing[{0.01,0.02}]},
                    Axes->False
                   ]

h2=SmoothHistogram[ Adataopt,
                    Automatic,
                    "PDF",
                    RegionFunction->Function[{x,y},0<x<10],
                    PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,0.5}},
                    Filling->Axis,
                    PlotLegends->{"P(Fopt)"},
                    PlotStyle->{Green,Dashing[{0.02,0.04}]},
                    Axes->False
                   ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Can you include an example figure from some other source as a reference perhaps? Also, I'm pretty confused by the `FindMinimum` on that interpolating function, given that you've specified no constraints, which means the minimum is -infinity.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @grampalis, what are those `Adatarob` and `Adataorb` stuff?

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks. i will have them in mind!

Comment: @march I included a low quality figure i made myself using Photoshop. Concerning the `FindMinimum`, firstly i am only interested in this specific region of the function `3.95<x<15.5` which demonstrates what i would like to explain in my essay. And secondly the interpolating function results in a 12th degree polynomial, even highest degree, with a positive coefficient for `x^12`. So, the minimum is a real number.

Comment: @garej my mistake, i forgot to paste two lines of code. They are the corresponding values of `y=f[x]`, the distributions of which I want to plot vertically on the y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the modifications that need to be done on your plots `h1` and `h2` in order to flip them over the line `y == x`. If you look "under the hood" at the structure of these two plots by executing, for instance,

```
FullForm@Normal@h1
```

you find that really there are only two objects, a `Line` and a `Polygon`. Both of these `Head`s take inputs which are lists of `{x, y}` lists, so all we need to do is go in "by hand" and reverse each one of these coordinate lists. To do this, we define a replacement rule

```
rule = {Line[a_] :> Line[Reverse /@ a], Polygon[a_] :> Polygon[Reverse /@ a]};
```

which will take all objects in an expression of the form `Line[ something ]` and `Map` `Reverse` over the `something`. In other words, we switch `x` and `y` in each of the coordinate lists inside `something`.

Then, we define new plots

```
h1New = Normal@h1 /. rule

h2New = Normal@h2 /. rule
```

For convenience, let's suppose that you called the `Plot`s for `f[x]`, `grob[x]`, and `gopt[x]`

```
plotF, plotgrob, and plotgopt
```

respectively. Then your final figure can be made using

```
plots = Show[plotf, plotgrob, plotgopt, h1New, h2New
  , AxesLabel -> {"x", "F"}
  , Ticks -> None
  , Axes -> {True, True}
  ,PlotRange -> {{0, 17}, {0, 14}}
]
```

Resulting in

[image]

Note that these are the correct histograms exactly as computed using `SmoothHistogram`, and it turns out that the red one is very narrow and tall and the green one is wide and short. If you don't care that the histograms need to be *exact*, we can play around a little with the values. I played around a little and came up with

```
h1New = Normal@h1 /. rule /. (pat : Line | Polygon)[x_] :> pat[{1/3 #1, 3.5 + 5 (#2 - 3.5)} & @@@ x]
```

which stretches the red histogram by a factor of 5 vertically about the y-value 3.5 at the same time that it scales the x-values by a factor of 1/3, and

```
h2New = Normal@h2 /. rule /. (pat : Line | Polygon)[x_] :> pat[{5 #1, #2} & @@@ x]
```

which stretches the green plot horizontally by a factor of 5. The result is

[image]

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much. I especially like the playing-around addition. I will be accepting your answer as a solution shortly!!